# What can I do if none of my weapons seem to work?

Tags: pc, lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

I've played a few levels of Lara Croft and the Guardian of Light with a friend yesterday, and ran into the most vexing behavior.

I was playing as Totec, and whenever I was using a weapon other than his basic spear I simply could not kill anything, even the most basic enemy. I could empty an entire ammo bar with an automatic weapon at something and it simply wouldn't die. Seeing how enemies are rather tough at this point, killing things with the spear was very impractical (and also reflected very badly on my score for the level).

Has anyone come across this issue and found a way to circumvent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the way to get around this is to change your weapons using the number keys (1-4) instead of the mouse wheel. Once you do that, your weapons work as they should, which is to say they kill the things you shoot at, and not just waste all of your ammo.